# Array Issue in guizero

Tags: python

I am writing a simple sort program in python and encounter this error. I want to add values to the array  (Inside GUI ).

```
RL[0]=Text(app,size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[0,14])
```

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Code:

```
    from guizero import App
    from guizero import App,Text
    from guizero import App,TextBox
    from guizero import App,PushButton
    from guizero import Slider
    from guizero import Picture,Window

    app=App(title="Sample",
                  height=480,
                  width=800,
                  layout='grid')
    #Update multi ,single,Initial

    app.bg =  "white"
    RL=("A","B","C","D","E","F")

    RL[0]=Text(app,"",size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[0,14])        
    RL[1]=Text(app,"",size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[1,14])        
    RL[2]=Text(app,"",size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[2,14])        
    RL[3]=Text(app,"",size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[3,14])        
    RL[4]=Text(app,"",size=10,font="Times New Roman",color="black",grid=[4,14])

    app.display()
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you can't change items by referencing the index like you could with a list. You have defined `RL` as a tuple. Change to `RL=["A","B","C","D","E","F"]`. Note, that is referred to as a _list_ in python, arrays are something else.

Comment: Thanks .
Can you help me with  example for array which can be used in guizero (Graphical user interface )

Comment: I did in my first comment?